# How can I programmatically react to folder changes?

Tags: linux

I have an application that needs to process large files after they are uploaded to the system. In Linux, is it possible to detect folder changes and have a script run automatically, or should I just run a cron job every minute to look for new files?

Comment: You may have more luck with this question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout [inotify](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478).  If your running a recent kernel it will be included.  There are numerous APIs for numerous languages out there for it.

Comment: I just want to run a Perl script when a file gets added to folder. Is this difficult to implement with inotify?

Comment: IT shouldn't be (I've never done it in Perl though), there are some modules in CPAN (http://search.cpan.org/search?query=inotify&mode=all) that will help take the pain out of the process.

Answer (score 4):

Ionotify, as David says, is what you're looking for. [Iowatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iwatch/) is a little Perl script that uses Ionotify, via Perl, to report changes to a filesystem. Assuming you've got a degree of Perl scripting experience you should be able to hack this into something that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need a File Alteration Monitor. Take a look on http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple frontend to FAMs, [fileschanged](http://fileschanged.sourceforge.net/) can be useful, at least for prototyping.